# Laravel don't parse variable in my mail

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to send an email with information from my database.

But Laravel has a really strange behavior.

When I write that in my mail file (`christmas.php`)

```
<p>{{ $data["user"]->name}} </p>
```

In the mail I received I simply get : `{{ $data["user"]->name}}`

It's like Laravel doesn't parse {{ }} at all ?

This is my PHP code

```
        $data = array('feedbacks' => $feedbacks, "user" => $user);

        Mail::send('emails.christmas', $data, function($message) use ($data)
        {
            $message->to($data['user']->email, $data['user']->name)->subject('Welcome!');
        });
```

I've got no error, and after sending email, my view is created with no problem. And as I say I receive the mail. This content is just bad.

I'm using Laravel 4.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your mail file is `christmas.php`

If you want Laravel to use Blade - you need to rename the file to `christmas.blade.php`

Comment: It's works good. Thanks.

Just also have to change my "Blade" code to {{ $user }} instead of {{ $data["user"]}} to not have an undefined variable.